# How to sort lisbox Items by item length vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listbox

if there is any method in vb.net to sort a listbox by item length e.g
there is a property in listbox to sort items alphabetically

```
listbox1.sorted = true
```

but how to sort by item length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
listbox1.DataSource = listbox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.ToString.Length).ToList
```

Comment: I think it should be `.Cast(Of object)` .

Comment: @Bala Yeah, that probably makes more sense with the ListBox.Items.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake! This is for a ListView and not a ListBox. [Here](http://gfaraj.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/custom-sorting-for-listbox-in-c/) is an example (C#) for a listbox custom sort.

You can assign an IComparer class to the ListViewItemSorter of the listview to compare the items based on length. This is a little cumbersome, but it gives you complete control over the sort order.

Here's an example (not tested. uColumn is the sort column):

```
ListView1.ListViewItemSorter = New lvSort
...
Class lvSort
Implements IComparer

Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer _
Implements IComparer.Compare

s1 = CType(x, ListViewItem).SubItems(uColumn).Text
s2 = CType(y, ListViewItem).SubItems(uColumn).Text

If s1.Length < s2.Length Then
  Return (-1)
ElseIf s1.Length > s2.Length Then
  Return (1)
Else
  Return (0)
End If

End Function
End Class
```

Comment: @xpda OP's using listbox not listview. is the Sorter still applicable?

Comment: Oops! I always get those mixed up.